# Anylogic GIS capability

Tags: google-maps, gis, google-maps-api-2, anylogic

I am currently working on my thesis in the field of last mile delivery in urban context.

I want to inquire about a capability of Anylogic software, we are developing an agent based simulation model of last mile delivery in urban context. One of the most important areas of simulation in our model, is to use the time and distance needed to move from point A to point B by the driver in our analysis.

Therefore, we are inquiring if Anylogic is capable of providing the user “us” with the time needed to move from Point A to Point B without assuming the speed of the driver, similar to the output provided from software such as Google Maps, OpenStreetMaps, etc… as the attached picture. We are wondering if Anylogic have a built in API to connect with the Distance Matrix API from Google Maps, that retrieves travel distances and time between start and end points as calculated by the Google Maps API.

This the link to the Google maps API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#Restrictions

So far I have used the provided openstreetmaps by Anylogic, but it only gives routes and produces time based on assumed speed for each agent which does not reflect the real life situations in the case of traffic jams and other causes that varies the travel time.

Thanks in advance!

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ4w2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but you need to have a valid subsription with Google to access their data. It is not cheap but if you have it, AnyLogic can access it via API.